# Shopify app that can use and save camera data

Tags: shopify

I would like to build a Shopify app that can take pictures of the customer using the selfie camera, save them to a customer profile, and allow for guest checkout. I know this is partly possible because this app - https://www.esenca.app is able to achieve the camera functionality component.

Regarding the fine details, how would I create a Shopify app that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you create a mobile App using your Flutter or React Native library (or whatever turns your mobile phone crank) with camera access. Ensure your App can take a picture and store it.

Second you would implement the Shopify oAuth pattern into your App, asking for customer permissions, so the merchant could choose to install this App in their store.

Third you would code up an extension in your App that displays this picture in the Customer account section of the App.

Fourth, clean up all the loose ends and profit from your adventure!

Comment: How would I know which pictures associate with which customers if they haven't logged in?

Comment: You wouldn't. But now you are getting way too specific for SO anyway, and you know darned well your question is pretty close to trolling, so I guess you go from there.